# Migrating to Rails 3.1 from 3.0.7 - Error: wrong number of arguments (3 for 2)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I'm trying to port an app to rails 3.1.

After updating the rails gem, I'm getting the following error:

`wrong number of arguments (3 for 2)`

The code involved is:

```
User.find_by_email('email')
```

in Application Controller.

- [Full Trace at Gist](https://gist.github.com/aee1804c9fd39ab9321a)

Any ideas? This was working fine in Rails 3.0.7

Thanks!

Comment: From what version of Rails are you porting the app? Have you run `rails new appname` on the app directory to upgrade all the boilerplate to the most recent version?

Comment: 3.0.7 - sorry for not mentioning that more clearly.

Comment: It would be much helpful if you could paste complete error trace.

Comment: I reverted back for now. For what it's worth, it works fine in the console, just not in Application Controller. I tried various mysql suggestions, but I'm using sqlite3.

Comment: Added full trace - https://gist.github.com/aee1804c9fd39ab9321a

Answer (score 2):

Update your `newrelic` gem. If that won't help, try disabling it.

See https://support.newrelic.com/discussions/support/5844-newrelic_rpm-gem-incompatible-with-not-yet-released-rails-31